# No puedo traspasar base de datos Realtime de firebase como quiero

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Buenas lo que requiero es que esta instancia de base de datos quede  asi, pero no me resulta, ya que al intentar traspasar me traspasa pero no como lo muestro a continuación :

```
  {
   "id":1,
  "listname":"2022-09-09 00:00:00",
  "products":[
     {
        "id":1,
        "idlist":1,
        "product":"leche",
        "quantity":1,
        "measure":"litro",
        "status":false
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "idlist":1,
        "product":"pan",
        "quantity":1,
        "measure":"Kg",
        "status":false
     },
     {
        "id":3,
        "idlist":1,
        "product":"huevos",
        "quantity":12,
        "measure":"unidades",
        "status":false
     },
     {
        "id":4,
        "idlist":1,
        "product":"queso",
        "quantity":1,
        "measure":"Kg",
        "status":true
     }
  ]},
```

Pero al ingresarlo en React Native, la primera vez, todo sale bien, pero al colocar un nuevo producto a la lista , me crea una lista nueva con todo los parámetros cuando ingreso por segunda vez, con el mismo Id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de ingreso estoy trabajando en React Native

```
export const addlist= (list, idList, nameList, product, quantity, measure, status) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${URL_API}/lists.json`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          listname: nameList,
          products: [
            {
              id: Date.now().toString(),
              idlist: idList,
              product: product,
              quantity: quantity,
              measure: measure,
              status: status,
            },
          ],
        }),
      });
      const resData = await response.json();
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_LIST,
        list,
        idList,
        nameList,
        product,
        quantity,
        measure,
        status
      });
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
};
```

Ojala me ayuden gracias

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la primera vez que lo creas te genera como lo que tu quieres por que estas haciendo un post, pero la segunda vez que lo realices deberías hacer un patch o un put ingresando el id del ya creado

Comment: Ya lo hice David Gracias por responder